# YAML to use repr/str when printing an object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, yaml

I have a dictionary where keys are objects. These objects can be thought as tuple wrappers and they do implement both `__hash__` and `__repr__`.

```
example = {
  Coordinates(0,0): Rome,
  Coordinates(0,1): Zurich
}
```

I want to print the dictionary with `yaml`, using the repr of the object. This would be the desired output:

```
(0, 0): Rome
(0, 1): Zurich
```

Instead, what I get is:

```
? !!python/object:__main__.Coordinates
  x: 0
  y: 0
: Rome
? !!python/object:__main__.Coordinates
  x: 0
  y: 1
: Zurich
```

I'm doing the transformation via:

```
import yaml
print(yaml.dump(example, allow_unicode=True, default_flow_style=False))
```

The only solution I found so far is to coerce everything to `str()` manually myself. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Assuming you're using PyYAML, have you looked into e.g. `add_representer `? https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#constructors-representers-resolvers

Comment: "I have a dictionary where keys are objects." Just an aside, keys in dictionaries are *always objects*

Comment: @jonrsharpe That actually works. Do you want to submit an answer or do you prefer me to do it? Bonus: show how to use add_representer() in order to achieve the exact desired output (I haven't been able to do it yet).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sure, though I clearly meant a non-primitive object. :)

Comment: I don't know any more than that, just looked for it in the docs! If you figure it out by all means write up your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the type `Coordinates` exists, this would be the setup:

```py
import yaml
from yaml.resolver import BaseResolver

def coord_representer(dumper, data):
  return dumper.represent_scalar(BaseResolver.DEFAULT_SCALAR_TAG,
      data.__repr__())

yaml.add_representer(Coordinates, coord_representer)
```

The `DEFAULT_SCALAR_TAG` ensures that PyYAML doesn't dump an explicit tag for the scalar `(x, y)`. You may want to use an actual YAML sequence instead:

```
def coord_representer(dumper, data):
  return dumper.represent_sequence(BaseResolver.DEFAULT_SEQUENCE_TAG,
    [data.x, data.y], flow_style=[True, True])
```

This will yield `[x, y]`, a YAML flow sequence. Problem is that this is tricky to read in again, as PyYAML would by default construct a list from it, which cannot be used as dict key.

Comment: The first solution proposed worked like a charm, thanks!